# Responssive grid for screen size 350px or less

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want 2nd column to appear in next row for screens less than 350px. But currently it's occurring for extra small screens(768px)(I am doing the same in my code). Is there any way to do for screen size 350px or less. This is what I am doing:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <style>
            @media (max-width: 768px) {
            .Labels {
             text-align: center;
             float: none;
             }
            .InputFields {
                text-align: center;
                float: none;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid grey;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 Labels" style="text-align: right;">FirstName</div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 InputFields" style="text-align: left;"><input type="text" size="20" maxlength="50"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 Labels" style="text-align: right;">LastName</div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 InputFields" style="text-align: left;"><input type="password" size="20" maxlength="50"></div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn`t close the first row ending div.

To achieve your requirement you need small modifications.

My Code. Try this

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <!-- loads the bootstrap css -->

    <style>
        .col-xs-6{
            width: 35%;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid grey;">
        <div class="row"><!-- first row -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">FirstName</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6" style="text-align: left;">
               <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="50"></div>
        </div><!-- end of first row --> 
        <div class="row"><!-- second row -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">LastName</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6" style="text-align: left;">
                 <input type="password" size="20" maxlength="50"></div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
 </html>
```